# How to split CSS Code with PHP if is has sub brackets?

Tags: php, css, parsing

i try to split my CSS Code stored in variables.
But i always get Problems if i have media queries or similiar.

I dont need all rules detailed, but how to solve to split at brackets if there can be brackets inside?

```
@media xyz { div { width: 100px; } a {color: blue;}}
#other-div { width: 200px; color: red;}
```

At the result i only want this to be the parts:

1: @mediy xzy

2. div { width: 100px; } a {color: blue;}

3: #other-div

4 width: 200px; color: red;

Removing comments, or splitting if i have only 2 results( whole block) will not be a problem, this i can solve by myself. But i cant solve the problem with brackets inside, than it allways breaks at the next closing bracket.

Comment: Don’t try and write this yourself, go find yourself a proper existing CSS parser somewhere instead.

Comment: All Parsers are to complicated, because i dont need to get all the rules, i just need the identifier to work with.
And all Parsers have their problems, i tryed csstidy (cant work with specials like webkit frames), sabberworm (having problems with content: '\231') and some more.

Comment: What do you mean by "i get problems"? Share your code and the error messages, and we'll see where it goes wrong

Comment: Thanks, the csstidy is allready removed.

With sabberworm when i just do it without modifing:
```
$parser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssoutput);
$oCss = $parser->parse();
$critical = $oCss->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
```
The output is changing content: '\421' to hyroglyphes.
I only want the critical css at the start so i tryed to remove the rule
```
foreach($oCss->getAllRuleSets() as $oRuleSet) {
 $oRuleSet->removeRule('content');
}
```
Thats not working because of the hyroglyphes.
I tryed nearly every characterset (at leats the input is utf-8..)

Comment: _“All Parsers are to complicated, because i dont need to get all the rules, i just need the identifier to work with. ”_ - well then have fun with CSS containing stuff like `#foo:before { content: "}"; }` etc. :-)

Comment: I've added my problems with the sabberworm parser as an full reply for a better overview. At least is think sabberworm is working best, the rest was more worse.
And this is why i thought it's easier to cut it by myself. But of course if the parser is working correct this will be a better solution. If someone known an good working Parser please tell me (i checked around 20-30 Topics in Stackoverflow and tested all results of this, with parser or just with preg_match_functions ..).

Answer (score 1):

For a better overview here is my code with Sabberworm.

First Step: Just load and save:

```
$parser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssoutput);
$oCss = $parser->parse();
$critical = $oCss->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
```

Result will be problems like:

```
fa-arrow-right:before{content:"ï¡";}.
```

Okay, so i tried to remove the rule like:

```
$parser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssoutput);
$oCss = $parser->parse();
foreach($oCss->getAllRuleSets() as $oRuleSet) {
    $oRuleSet->removeRule('content');
}
$critical = $oCss->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
```

But this is deleting much more, i cant specially find why and how, but the css is around the half of before

And my Main Part (pq is the function for phpQuery) is resulting with an error (aswell commenting removerule part out)

```
$parser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssoutput);
$oCss = $parser->parse();
foreach($oCss->getAllDeclarationBlocks() as $oBlock) {
    foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector) {
        echo "selektor: ".$oSelector->getSelector()."<br>";
        if(!pq($oSelector->getSelector())->length)
        {
            $oBlock->removeSelector($oSelector);
        }
    }

    if(count($oBlock->getSelectors()) === 0)
        $oCss->remove($oBlock);
}

$critical = $oCss->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
```

The error: Uncaught Sabberworm\CSS\Parsing\OutputException: Attempt to print declaration block with missing selector [line no: 20] in /var/www/vho...

Comment: The iconfont problem i simply solved by changing the characters before:`$cssoutput = str_replace('\f','###f',$cssoutput);` and afterwards `$critical = str_replace('###f','\f',$critical);`  but the problem with the error about the missing selector in the blocks i cant figure out until now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

$css = "@media xyz { div { width: 100px; } a {color: blue;}}
#other-div { width: 200px; color: red;}";

// split by line break
$lines = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $css);

$parts = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {

  // parse everything that's not "{" unit first "{" and the rest until last "}"
  preg_match_all('/^([^{]+)\{(.+)\}/', $line, $matches);

  // remove total result
  array_shift($matches);

  // remove second array level + trim
  $matches = array_map(function($match) {
    $match = array_shift($match);
    return trim($match);
  }, $matches);

  // add to parts array
  $parts = array_merge($parts, $matches);
}

var_dump($parts);
//array(4) {
//  [0] =>
//  string(10) "@media xyz"
//  [1] =>
//  string(38) "div { width: 100px; } a {color: blue;}"
//  [2] =>
//  string(10) "#other-div"
//  [3] =>
//  string(25) "width: 200px; color: red;"
//}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe my mistake: That's only working if i have the rules in allways one line, but that was just for an example. I need to check the whole string.